# Database number columns automatically casting to integers

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Using the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract to retrieve table rows, my BIGINT fields are being automatically cast to integers. This is not required, and on 32 bit systems is obviously a bug waiting to happen.

Is there a simple way to keep these values as strings without setting up complex mapping classes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the database adapter (on the PHP side, not ZF side) itself isn't doing that?

I know PDO_MySQL and MySQLi both do that by default, though I'm not 100% sure how they handle BIGINT values on 32bit vs 64bit systems.